# cx_Oracle silently crashes on connect in python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, oracle, ipython, cx-oracle

I use Windows 7, 64bit, with installed Python 2.7 and Oracle instant client 10.2.0.3.

I try to set up connection with Oracle database from python. In order to do this, I download cx_Oracle-5.1.2-10g.win32-py2.7.msi and install it.

upd. it's an error. i meant cx_Oracle-5.1.2-10g.win-amd64-py2.7.msi

Then I try to connect use code like this

```
import cx_Oracle
ad = cx_Oracle.makedsn('127.0.0.1', '1521', 'XE')
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'password', ad)
```

And check that connection is set up correctly by selecting some rows from database table.

And at this moment happens something interesting.
I perform described actions in three different environments: Sublime Text 3, Python Console and ipython.

The problem is in ST3 and in ipython this chunk of code silently crashes on line with `cx_Oracle.connect` (I checked that with `print` statement in different places).

But in python console and idle it works just fine. Moreover sometimes it works properly in ipython, but I cannot understand why and when. In ST3 it never works.

ST shows message `[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 3221226356]`

To demonstrate behavior in python and ipython console I attach copypaste of simple case from cmd. It just exits from ipython.

```
C:\Users\Alexey>python
Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun  1 2014, 14:21:57) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> cx_Oracle.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

>>> exit()

C:\Users\Alexey>ipython
Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun  1 2014, 14:21:57) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import cx_Oracle

In [2]: cx_Oracle.connect()

C:\Users\Alexey>
```

Where is the problem? How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

PS. I tried to handle exception in ST3 and ipython such as

```
try:
  cx_Oracle.connect()
except Exception as e:
  print e
```

but script terminates on cx_Oracle.connect() and no message appears.

Comment: That sounds like there's a bug in the compiled part of cx_Oracle, and it's crashing without raising a Python exception.

Comment: When I google this problem I found nothing about it. I think wrong configuration on my computer takes place in this situation, but I cannot understand what is it. But maybe you are write and this is bug, I hope developers still support this lib.

Comment: It looks like it's still maintained - it had a 5.1.3 release a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this environment myself and did not experience the same behavior. Perhaps use faulthandler or gdb or some equivalent to figure out where the crash is taking place? cx_Oracle is still maintained (by me) so if you can find a bug I'll happily fix it! It may also be a problem with IPython or ST3 or in some interaction between these two and cx_Oracle. Since I can't replicate the problem, however, you'll need to provide a stack trace of some sort so we can proceed further.